# Remove parantheses only if inside characters more than one

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to remove parantheses only if inside them is more than one character of text.

My input is:

`$string = "Model name (4) Color (Additional Params)"`

My desired final output string should be: "Model name (4) Color Additional Params".

My solution is:

1. Detect needed scope with Regex `\([^)]{2,}\)`.
2. Cut it from original string.
3. Remove parantheses.
4. Attach back to original string.

I know that regular expressions have Conditional statements. But I can't understand logic of using them.

Is it possible to do with single regex and how?

Comment: You don't need a conditional statement. Add a capturing group around the negated character class and use that in the replacement `\(([^)]{2,})\)` Note that `[^)]` could also match a newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do with one regex:

```php
$string = 'Model name (4) Color (Additional Params) and some other (a) with more (params)';
$modifiedString = preg_replace('/\(([^\(\)]{2,})\)/', '$1', $string);
var_dump($modifiedString);
```

This will give:

> string(74) "Model name (4) Color Additional Params and some other (a) with more params"

Pattern explained:

- `\(` - match literal opening parenthesis
- `[^\(\)]` - match any character that is not either an opening or closing parenthesis (we need to do this so it wouldn't match everything between the first opening and last closing parenthesis - `(4) Color (Additional Params)`)
- it is followed by a quantifier `{2,}` saying we want to match two or more of these
- together with the quantifier it is wrapped in parentheses, forming a *capturing group*: `([^\(\)]{2,})` - this will get the entire contents of the parentheses in the string
- finally we match `\)` literal closing parenthesis

The second parameter in the `preg_replace` call is defining to replace our full match `(Additional params)` with the capturing group `Additional params`.